# Is there an equivalent to a Living annuity in Germany?

Tags: germany, annuity

Is there a similar product in Germany to the South African living annuity versus a guaranteed annuity?
We have double citizenship, South African and German. Born in South Africa and emigrated to Germany 10 years ago. Never worked in Germany, so we do not have a pension insurance here. Now we need to plan for future. We are aged 66 and 74.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe the features of the product you are interested in-- not a lot of folks are going to be really familiar with both South African and German financial systems.  My guess is that you are looking for an immediate annuity not a guaranteed annuity.  But there may be some features of a SA living annuity that you are looking for that would be different